# How do I add "-b" in cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I need to execute cURL methods that equals the below one in PHP because I wanna persist cookies when it redirects.

```
curl -b test.cookie -L http://website.com
```

I tried to set some options in curl_setopt() as below, but I couldn't get the answer.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    //  :
    // Some lines are hidden here.
    //  :
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'test.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'test.txt',
));

$html = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Does anyone have good ideas?

Comment: When you say '_I couldn't get the answer_', what do you mean? What is currently happening and what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: That means "I haven't had a solution yet."

Comment: But specifically, what have you tried and what was the outcome? Are you getting an error, is the screen just white, the request comes back unsuccessfully?